# How to make an ajax call run one after another?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to insert a record and then retrieve it after adding it to the database, however the the second ajax call which retrieves it should wait after the record has been inserted. Any ideas on how to go about this?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#addPersonnelForm").on("submit", function() {

    departmentName = $("#selectPersonnelDepartment option:selected").text();
    $.ajax({
      url: "php/insertPersonnel.php",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "JSON",
      data: {
        firstName: $("#addPersonnelFirstName").val(),
        lastName: $("#addPersonnelLastName").val(),
        emailAddress: $("#addPersonnelEmailAddress").val(),
        jobTitle: $("#addPersonnelJobTitle").val(),
        departmentID: $("#selectPersonnelDepartment").val()
      },
      success: function(result) {}
    });
  });
});

$.ajax({
  url: "php/retrievePersonnel.php",
  type: "POST",
  dataType: "JSON",
  success: function(result) {}
});
```

The database is already populated and when I launch the application it retrieves the last record for example record 100 but it should retrieve record 101 hence I want the second AJAX call to wait after insertion.

Comment: So why are you not calling it in the success method?

Comment: The second AJAX isn't even waiting for `$(document).ready()`.

Comment: 1) make the second call inside success/done 2) use an ajax queue (implementations available on SO questions) 3) use some sort of dodgy "is_loaded" flag to determin when to call retrievePersonnel (protip: don't do this)

Comment: given $.ajax returns a Promise, async/await should work just fine and prevent nested callbacks.

Comment: Why do you not return inserted registry as part of insert Ajax response!? Why the second Ajax call !? I don't understand

Comment: Calling it in the success method doesn't work.

Comment: @oooo  1) are there any errors in the console in the browser?   2) can you contirm the success() method is being called (by adding a console.log() as the first statement in the handler. 3) it could be that an error is being generated. If you add the error handler callback function and put a console.log() in there, you can see if this is happening.

Comment: There are no errors. I have tried your answer and it still doesn't work placing the second ajax call into the first ajax success function.

Answer (score -1):

You can call the second ajax request from within the callback of the first request to sequence the requests.

```
$.ajax({
      url: "php/insertPersonnel.php",
      ...
      success: function(result) {
          // Process Result
          $.ajax({
              url: "php/retrievePersonnel.php",
              ...
              success: function(result2) {
                  // Process result2 
              }
          });
      }
});
```

Use can also use the Query ajax .done() function to chain requests.

```
$.ajax({
  // first request...
})
.done(function(){
  $.ajax({
    // second request
  });
});
```

(See here for full details: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

(Note: to clarify the comments below my answer I originally suggested that the success callback was deprecated.  This is not the case)

Comment: This is a very common misconception, the success method as used in the question is in fact *not* deprecated. what's deprecated is `.success`, which was used in place of `.done` in very old versions of jquery.

Comment: "*see ... for details*" - nothing on that page even suggests `success:` should not be used.  The closest is under `done()` : *An alternative construct to the success callback option*

Comment: Hey you guys are correct, for years I have been reading that wrong!  I shall ammend my answer.  Thanks for pointing that out to me.